# How to programmatically make text selectable and provide popup menus to go to another app

Tags: ios, uimenucontroller

I am trying to implement a feature in iOS project that when you select a piece of text and highlight it you can then choose from the menu options to use another app like the default dictionary. Is it possible to do this? If so where can I find such documentation or tutorials?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/EditMenu.html

Comment: @Pang Please give some useful advice instead of posting a link for general information. I actually read the entire article about Text Programming Guide before I ask this question.

Comment: 1. You were asking for documentation, so I gave documentation. 2. There're 2 parts in your question - making text selectable, and providing custom options. You can show us relevant code and/or tell us which part you're having problem.

Comment: @Pang OK thanks. I will keep posting relevant source code here in case I have problems in the future.

Comment: And you've tried *what* so far? Lazy.

Comment: @AshleyMills I came here to search for help and I post my research and solution underneath for people who have similar problem. If you can't offer any help please don't say anything and just walk away.

Comment: The correct way to ask a question in this case would be to show the research you had done, and give samples of the code you had written.  Not show nothing and ask for tutorial links. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem.
Thanks to the author of this article:
http://blog.studiovillegas.com/2014/02/06/ios-uipasteboard-uimenucontroller-and-uimenuitem/

To add a custom menu item on to the default menu controller.

**ViewController.h**

```
- (void)longPressGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIMenuItem *mi = [self.label menuItemOpenPleco];
    UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    menuController.menuItems = @[mi];
}
```

**PasteboardLabel {h,m}**

```
@interface PasteboardLabel : UILabel

- (UIMenuItem *)menuItemOpenPleco;

@end

@implementation PasteboardLabel

- (UIMenuItem *)menuItemOpenPleco
{
    return [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Open Pleco" action:@selector(openPleco:)];
}

- (void)openPleco:(id)sender
{
    NSString *selectedText = [self textInRange:[self selectedTextRange]];
    UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    pb.string = selectedText;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"plecoapi://x-callback-url/q?s=%@", pb.string];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the iOS *menu*. Look at the documentation on classes such as UIMenu, UIMenuItem, and UIMenuController.

Comment: And see my examples online, such as this one for selection in a text field: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch23.html#_the_text_field_menu

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there's a dearth of examples of adding custom menu items, or explanations of how they work. So I wanted to resolve that by sharing a few important tidbits then showing an example.

1. *The* `UIMenuController` "talks" with `UIView`s, not with `UIViewController`s. This means that your `UIMenuController` related code needs to go into subclasses of `UIView` rather than a `UIViewController`.
2. Notice the word *The* at the start of my prior example. There's only one `UIMenuController`, a singleton which is shared from when your application first starts until it ends. This means that you should only add your item once, and that you shouldn't be writing over the existing array of items.
3. The appearance of the button in the `UIMenu` is based on whether or not the `UIView` that was tapped responds to the selector. This means you need to implement the method if you want the button to appear, and that you don't need to worry about it appearing when unrelated views are tapped unless you pick a selector name for which other UIViews also have methods.

So, having said all that, I made a subclass of a `UITextView` (which means its a subclass of `UIView` per my first bullet) and then I gave it this `initialize` method, along with an implementation for my selector.

```
+ (void)initialize {
    static dispatch_once_t addInsert;
    dispatch_once(&addInsert, ^{
        UIMenuController *mController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        UIMenuItem *insert = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Insert..."
                                                        action:@selector(insert:)];
        mController.menuItems = [mController.menuItems arrayByAddingObject:insert];
    });
}

- (void)insert:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Insert... pressed!");
}
```

The important points above here:

1. It's in the class `initialize` method, which is called by the runtime before the first time any other method in your class is invoked. In practice means the code is handled just before the first time an instance of your custom view will be appearing on screen.
2. I added a `dispatch_once` guard around it. If my class is subclassed, it's possible that those subclasses will call this `initialize` method. Maybe those subclasses show up before this one does, so I don't want to prevent the `initialize` method from running then. I just want to prevent it from running multiple times. Thus why I wrapped the code in a `dispatch_once`.
3. I didn't just set the `menuItems` to a new array of items - I assigned it to a new array of items that extended the existing array of items with my new item.

Hope you find all of that helpful. It's not very complicated, and you can certainly go about implementing my second point in other ways - I tried to pick a way that seemed safest to me, but there are certainly simpler ways of doing it.